# jakarta 9.1 Facelets XHTML page namespace directives

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, namespaces, xhtml

I just started an new EE-project based on jakarta EE 9.1 with jsf. Jakarta EE 9 is new, so I start very simple with Wildfly 25.
The first tests results in:
"javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test.xhtml @15,55 value="#{bean.input}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null"
Meanwhile I changed the namespace directives of web.xml to:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee 
                         https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" >
```

For the bean.xml to:

```
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee 
                         https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0" bean-discovery-mode="all">
```

and for the faces-config to:

```
<faces-config version="3.0"
   xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee 
                   https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd">
```

I guess this is correct so far. But I'm stuck with the test.xhtml with the declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
```

My simple test still get the same error message, so I suspect, the declaration should also be something like:

```
<html lang="en" 
   xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xmlns:f="https://jakarta.xxx.xxx/jsf/core" 
   xmlns:h="https://jakarta.xxx.xxx/jsf/html">
```

But I can't find the correct declaration. Hwo knows it?s